# Laravel wait till Transaction is finished?

Tags: php, laravel

How can i run something after a transaction is completed?

for example:

```
$message = array();

DB::transaction(function() use (...) {
     $message = array('12345');  
}

return response()->json($message, 200); // == []
```

How can i wait till the closure is finished? when ill try with:

```
DB::transaction(function() use (...)
{
     return response()->json($message, 200); // no response
}
```

Any ideas?

Ill already found a solution by myself now, when ill use:

```
$message = DB::transaction(function() use (...) {
     return array('12345');  
}

// then $message is correct
```

Comment: Your first example should work exactly like you want it to.  It wouldn't try to run whatever is in the closure and the rest of your code concurrently, it will wait for the closure to finish.  Is there something happening that makes you think this isn't the case?

Comment: No its not working, but ill already found a solution by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions are not processed asynchronously, so you don't have to worry about that. However, reading between the lines it would seem as if your challenge is actually how to modify data inside of a closure when not defined locally. The answer is to `use(&$data)`.

The `use` statement for the `closure` scope will actually localize the variable to the closure allowing you to read from it, and write to it. However, as usual, the variable must be `passed by reference` in order to return the modified value after the closure has finished working with it, like this:

```
$message = array();

DB::transaction(function) use(&$message) {
    $message = array('12345');
});

return response()->json($message);
```

Also, don't forget to commit your transactions prior to returning:

```
DB::commit();
```

In fact, for your scenario, I'd advise wrapping it all in a `try/catch` statement, which, when coupled with transactions, allows you to handle any scenario for errors / success that may be met during the transaction process:

```
try {
    $message = array();
    DB::transaction(function() use(&$message) {
        $message = array(1,2,3,4,5);
    });

    DB::commit();

    return response()->json($message, 200);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();

    return response()->json($e->getMessage, 422);
}
```

**Note** the `422` is Laravel's recommended error code to return when you're met with `unprocessable entities`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explanation!

Comment: I believe a lot of this is unnecessary.  Laravel will commit for you and even rollback for you in the event of an `Exception` or `Throwable`.

Comment: @user3158900 I understand that best practices may differ between developers, but I'm not entirely sure what issue you find with my answer?

Comment: If you dive into `Illuminate\Database\Connection` and look at the `transaction` function, it's already calling `commit()` and `rollback()` when appropriate.  I think it greatly simplifies your answer if you remove `DB::commit()` and `DB::rollback()` because they aren't required.

Comment: @user3158900 Understood. I usually just provide the full step through process because of the confusion between `transaction` and `beginTransaction`. Can't win them all I suppose.